# ipad : how to change background color for Ipad app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, background

I am developing application for iPhone and iPad both, its working fine in iPhone but for iPad it gives this full gray background color, while I want full blue background color. I am using two xib files and doing this in code. I works fine with iphone but not with ipad.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoginHeaderViewController" owner:self options:nil];
     self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView;


     [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LoginFooterViewController" owner:self options:nil];
     self.tableView.tableFooterView = tableFooterView;
     self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: (66.0/255) green: (142.0/255) blue: (189.0/255) alpha: 1.0]; 

}
```

I even put these lines In above code then It gives the below pic result otherwise it show all gray background.

```
  tableHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: (66.0/255) green: (142.0/255) blue: (189.0/255) alpha: 1.0]; 
  tableFooterView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: (66.0/255) green: (142.0/255) blue: (189.0/255) alpha: 1.0];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
[myTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 tableview.backgroundColor = color;
```

Set background view to nil using following :

```
 tableview.backgroundView = nil;
```

Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

If you want blue background color then there is no need to assign color to **tableHeader** and **tableFooter** as the color of self.view is blue. So make the following changes:

```
tableHearder.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableHeader.backgroundView = nil;

tableFooter.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tableFooter.backgroundView = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[myTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[myTableView setBackgroundView:[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

This will suit your background color change